# How to use Find/Replace Wildcard on Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, microsoft-word-2010, wildcards

I made a mistake on a huge word document (100 pages) and I would to fix it quickly using the wildcard.

I tried to use many different options but could not find the right command to use.

*Example on my word document:*

**Reception:**

The valuation for the reception is more than 3 days (including the house).

**Organization:**

The valuation for the organization is more than 7 days (including the retails).

I would like to remove on all my document the part reception until the organization (without organization) to have at the end:

**Organization:**

The valuation for the organization is more than 7 days (including the retails).

Someone could help me on the right wildcard syntax please?
I tried: <Reception:*?<Organization:?* but it takes organization as well. I tried to use [!] but it is not working as well...

Thanks for your help,
Stef

Answer (score 0):

Word does not support Regex - you need to use wildcards.

Use the following inside the "Find and Replace" dialog :

- Click `More >>`
- Check `Use wildcards`
- Enter the following values:

  - Find what : `Reception*Organization`
  - Replace with : `Organization`
- Click `Find Next` to check your input
- If everything is correct, click `Replace All`

Comment: This can be done without wildcards as well. Find: Reception:^pThe valuation for the reception is more than 3 days (including the house).^p  Replace: nothing

Comment: @KnotWright: The example shows that not all have 3 days.

Comment: I'm reading this differently.  There is only one example of what should be deleted, and that is the entire Reception section with no mention of any variation.  The Organization section shows 7 days, but that section isn't being removed.

Comment: Thanks HarryMC, the only issue I have with that method is that Organization have a specific header. Is there a way to keep the header as well?

Comment: @killua: I need a real example to answer that. Can you post a small file online?

Comment: harrymc's formulas will work if you replace 'Organization' with '.^13'  in the find section and replace with nothing.  This finds up to the period and paragraph return at the end of the Reception section (assuming they are all one sentence like your example) and deletes that section.  It doesn't touch the Organization section so your header should remain unaffected.  Also, The method I outline above will achieve this with no wildcards if the reception section is identical throughout because it simply removes the Reception section and its paragraph marks word for word.